# DNS Not Resolving For All Users

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7.5, domain-name

I recently transferred one of my domains to a new server, and ever since I am having intermittent issues accessing the site. taxiwayalpha.com does not work, www.taxiwayalpha.com occasionally works, and email also does not work.

Despite trying a couple of DNS testing utils online, it appears that the domain is not resolving to the server correctly.

A Whois check shows the following nameservers:

```
Primary Name Server Hostname: NS1.GAVINCOATES.COM
Secondary Name Server Hostname: NS2.GAVINCOATES.COM
```

The domain gavincoates.com is configured on the same server, and this website resolves fine.

The domain gavincoates.com is configured as follows with the registrar (simplynames.com)
[image: gavincoates.com domain settings]

Within plesk on the server, the configuration for gavincoates.com is as follows:

[image: gavincoates.com hosting settings in plesk]

The hosting settings in Plesk for taxiwayalpha.com domain is as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you change the name servers for the domain too?

Answer (score 6):

First, check the `.com` servers:

```
% dig @a.gtld-servers.net. taxiwayalpha.com ns
...
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
taxiwayalpha.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1.gavincoates.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns2.gavincoates.com.
...
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.gavincoates.com.    172800  IN  A   69.65.102.34
ns2.gavincoates.com.    172800  IN  A   205.234.100.228
```

These appear to be the old server addresses?

Let's also check `ns1.gavincoates.com.`:

```
% dig @ns1.gavincoates.com. taxiwayalpha.com ns
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
taxiwayalpha.com.   86400   IN  NS  ns.taxiwayalpha.com.
...
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.taxiwayalpha.com.    86400   IN  A   212.67.209.138
```

Uh oh, we have a mismatch.  Your records at the `.com` registry are inconsistent both in name *and* in the glue records.

You need to have your domain updated with your registrar to use the right name (`ns.taxiwayalpha.com.` ) *and* because the `NS` is in its own zone you'll need to send them the right IP address for its glue record too.

Comment: I have changed the NS record in plesk for taxiwayalpha.com from NS to NS1, and the website now appears to load correctly. However, doing `dig @a.gtld-servers.net. taxiwayalpha.com ns` still shows the old IP addresses. Why is this, and what is a glue record? The only setting for the domain with the registrar, is to use ns1/ns2.gavincoates.com as the name server.

Comment: @GavinCoates you should talk to your registrar - they should be able to advise how to change the parent zone's NS records and add the glue record.

Comment: @GavinCoates p.s. despite what you've written above, according to Verisign the name servers for `gavincoates.com` are `ns[01].phase8.net` - they are _not_ pointing at your own server.

Comment: gavincoates.com nameserver is not set, instead I have created a series of A records that point to the correct server IP - see image 1 in my original post. Is this not correct?

Comment: @GavinCoates it has to be set both in the parent zone _and_ in the zone itself, and the two _should be consistent_.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that delegation to taxiwayalpha.com is set to ns1.gavincoates.com and ns2.gavincoates.com however querying the zone returns only ns.taxiwayalpha.com.

A second issue is that both ns1.gavincoates.com and ns2.gavincoates.com **resolve to the same address**. This is the same address that ns.taxiwayalpha.com resolves to.

```
$ host ns1.gavincoates.com.
ns1.gavincoates.com has address 212.67.209.138
$ host ns2.gavincoates.com.
ns2.gavincoates.com has address 212.67.209.138
```

I have performed a `dig` against your DNS server and it seems to respond with the records correctly:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> @ns1.gavincoates.com. taxiwayalpha.com. any
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1716
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 10, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;taxiwayalpha.com.              IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      MX      10 aspmx.l.google.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      SOA     ns.taxiwayalpha.com. contact.gavincoates.com. 1323190098 10800 3600 604800 10800
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns.taxiwayalpha.com.
taxiwayalpha.com.       86400   IN      A       212.67.209.138

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.taxiwayalpha.com.    86400   IN      A       212.67.209.138

;; Query time: 36 msec
;; SERVER: 212.67.209.138#53(212.67.209.138)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 19 15:21:40 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 315
```

Did you leave enough propagation time after changing server before running your tests?

Comment: I have left it for about 4 days to allow any changes to fully propogate. What exactly do you mean by ` querying the zone returns only ns.taxiwayalpha.com` - and how do i go about changing this?

Comment: See Alnitak's answer above. You need to fix your zone file as well as your glue records.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Nameservers are not responding correctly.

http://www.intodns.com/taxiwayalpha.com

Not the items in red. These will typically result in odd DNS behavor.

Appears your nameservers are not returning NS records for your domain.  You need to have NS records for your domain.

Comment: why are my ns1/ns2 showing the old server IP addresses? I guess this is what is causing problems, yet everything on the domain is configured to use the new IP addresses??